# How to know when all QAbstractItemModel::data() functions finished

Tags: c++, qt

I wrote a `QAbstractItemModel` based class and implemented `data(const QModelIndex & ar_index, int a_role) const` function. I refresh the model using:

```
beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), 0, 0);
// fill model
endInsertRows();
```

Inside data function I update some information `X` needed after refreshing.

I checked that `data` functions are invoked after refreshing the model and debugging I verified that my `X` variable is properly setted.

After refreshing, I need to fill another widget with this `X` value. How do I know that all data refresh was finished and correctly show `X`value? Which signal is emmited after completelly refreshing the model?

Comment: You refresh model data in data( ... ) **const**?

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard signal to use here -- the Qt's MVC API is designed to support not only static models, but also the dynamic ones, and for these, there cannot ever be a signal telling "all done". For example, in Trojita, a Qt IMAP e-mail client, `rowsInserted` is emitted to indicate that a new e-mail has arrived, but this happens even before the library knows anything about the new arrivals -- not even their UIDs. Only after the remote server has responded to the library's commands with data, the `dataChanged` is emitted to indicate that the "data represented by the model" has changed and that the attached views shall update.

You said you're reimplementing your own QAIM from scratch. This means that you can set any contracts you see fit here. Are some of the data immutable, i.e. guaranteed to never change after they have been loaded? If so, you can use a custom role like `RoleIsItemFetched` and after each change to the model (that is, after `modelReset`, `rowsInserted`, `rowsMoved` and `dataChanged`) check whether your `data(someIndex, RoleIsItemFetched).toBool()` function returns true. If so, you have your data, if not, you have to keep waiting.

An alternative to that might be to introduce your own signal. Don't be afraid of that, the MVC API is great for presenting data to users, but if you think you need more control over what is returned and have full control over the model and the "views", go ahead and make the code do what *you* need.